# Python Thread that runs at the start of every minute

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi there i need to implement a thread which runs at the beggining of every minute. The execution flow  should look like this.

```
start
sleep until hh.mins.00
do something
sleep until hh.mins.00
do something
sleep ..........
................
```

What is the best approach?

Comment: use a timer that starts a new thread every minute ?

Comment: It all depends on how accurate it has to be. Do you need it to be precisely on the minute? Timer threads with sleep statements tend to drift when running for a long time.

Comment: That is very difficult. As the timer starts on the interrupt, the accurrcy is 1000Hz in most linux dist--it means the system can start the process at HH.ss.00ms, but can not start the process at HH.ss.ms.01mirco sec. Moreover, it is really difficult to have the interrupt at the time HH.ss.00ms, it will have some delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think I found a solution, it have some delay as [Mr.c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2438804/mr-c) explained.

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        time.sleep(10-time.time()%10) #sleep to the start of next min
        print time.time()
```

Here is a 10secs simulation..

```
1401966250.0
1401966260.01
1401966270.01
1401966280.0
1401966290.01
1401966300.01
1401966310.01
1401966320.01
1401966330.01
1401966340.0
1401966350.01
1401966360.01
1401966370.0
1401966380.01
1401966390.0
1401966400.01
1401966410.0
1401966420.0
1401966430.0
1401966440.0
1401966450.0
1401966460.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `sched` Python module.  You say "run at exact time X" or "run after Y seconds have elapsed."  It's standard, and supports multiple threads.

Example from the [fine documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html)

```
>>> import sched, time
>>> s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
>>> def print_time(): print "From print_time", time.time()
...
>>> def print_some_times():
...     print time.time()
...     s.enter(5, 1, print_time, ())
...     s.enter(10, 1, print_time, ())
...     s.run()
...     print time.time()
...
>>> print_some_times()
930343690.257
From print_time 930343695.274
From print_time 930343700.273
930343700.276
```